# Using Sendmail + WAMP, but PHP errors indicate wrong SMTP server

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail

I'm using sendmail on a WAMP setup to try to be able to send emails using a remote SMTP server that requires authentication.  Even though i believe I have my php.ini file set up correctly and sendmail configured correctly, I get php about not being able to connect to the smtp server at localhost... but i'm trying to connect to a remote server!

from PHP.ini:

```
    [mail function]
    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/smtp
    ;SMTP = localhost
    ; http://php.net/smtp-port
    ;smtp_port = 25

    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-from
    ;sendmail_from = you@yourdomain

    ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-path
    sendmail_path =sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"

    ; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
    ; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
    ; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
    ;mail.force_extra_parameters =

    ; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
    mail.add_x_header = On

    ; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
    ; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
    ;mail.log =
    ; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on NT, not valid in Windows 95).
    ;mail.log = syslog
```

sendmail.ini:

```
    ; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.*******.***

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=2525

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=tls

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=*****@******.***
auth_password=******

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SMTP = localhost
    smtp_port = 25
```

Uncomment above two lines in your php.ini

Also, change

```
sendmail_path =sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

to

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```